# Not able to get data through API...!

Tags: magento2, database, api, rest-api, postman

Error is "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5dee36e254394".

When you run http://localhost:8888/magento/rest/V1/position/1

Need to get result from "position" column.

Api is for retrieving a column field by given user input.

```
<?php
 namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Model;

use SimpleMagento\Custom\Api\InfoLinkInterface;
use SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Info\CollectionFactory; //Collection file
use SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\InfoFactory; //Implemented getter setter model

class InfoLink implements InfoLinkInterface
{
   private $collection;
   private $infoFactory;
   public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collection,InfoFactory $infoFactory)
{
    $this->collection=$collection;
    $this->infoFactory=$infoFactory;
} 
/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return \SimpleMagento\Custom\Api\Data\InfoInterface[]
 */

public function getInfo($id)
{

    return $this->infoFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$id)->getData();
    //return $this->infoFactory->create()->getData('position')->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',1);

}
 }

?>
```

**webapi.xml** is

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

<route url="/V1/position/:id" method="GET">
    <service class="SimpleMagento\Custom\Api\InfoLinkInterface" method="getInfo"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: Can you please add here var/report/api or exception.log ?

Comment: `2019-12-09 12:57:41] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5dee44c52bdb3; Message: Class SimpleMganeto\Custom\Model\InfoLink does not exist {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: -1): Report ID: webapi-5dee44c52bdb3; Message: Class SimpleMganeto\\Custom\\Model\\InfoLink does not exist at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class SimpleMganeto\\Custom\\Model\\InfoLink does not exist at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []`

Comment: Make sure flush cache after change in di.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you added wrong model file class name in your `di.xml` file :

Change from :

> SimpleMganeto\Custom\Model\InfoLink

To :

> SimpleMagento\Custom\Model\InfoLink

Comment: Thanks a lot for correction but not able to get, even after that. Code flow of developing API is corect, right? . To make it more simple I ll write SQL query , from which is I want to get result. **SELECT POISITION FROM NEW INFO WHERE ENTITY_ID=$ID **

Comment: You added addFieldToFilter with entity_id. I think it should be position.

Comment: what you get data in getInfo function?

Comment: just a string from position column

Comment: If there will be unique record in your table. Then, you can use $record = $this->infoFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$id)->getLastItem(); ................ and then you can return, $record->getPosition(); or $record['position'];

Comment: http://localhost:8888/magento/rest/V1/position/1 . This URL i'm trying to pass in postman

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line

```
return $this->infoFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$id)->getData();
```

With this one

```
return $this->infoFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('eq', $id))->getFirstItem()->getPosition();
```

Follow this [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-api/) for reference.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if you need any help then. ;)

Comment: we just need to add ** http://localhost:8888/magento/rest/V1/position/1 **  This in postman right?   So that :id=1

Comment: Yes, @AkashKilledar. Right

Comment: but error in postman is  "message": "Server internal error. See details in report api/617778416808" :- 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface.

Comment: Can you please send me full error ?

Comment: Try to use "InfoLinkFactoryInterface" instead of "InfoLinkInterface" this in InfoLink.php file and run setup upgrade command once and check again.